# Unable to return value from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return value from the function which contains an anonymous function.

```
function getSingleCheckedItemId() {
    return $(".data-table-chk-item").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          var value = $(this).attr("value");
          return value;
      }
    });
  }
```

In this case it returns me the array of all checkboxes. If I remove the first `return`, it won't return a value but `undefined`.

So how do I return the value from `getSingleCheckedItemId()`?

Comment: try using `filter` instead of `each`. Or `map` if you definitely need to grab the value.

Comment: @dystroy, maybe. But I think he can learn more by hitting the docs for those functions himself. Also I don't have time right now to inspect jQuery's impls...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) always returns the jQuery object containing all elements that you iterated over so:

```
function getSingleCheckedItemId() {
    var ret;
    $(".data-table-chk-item").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          ret = $(this).attr("value");
          return false; //breaks out of .each
      }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Also, `this.value` is usually a better option than `$(this).attr('value')` in case you're dealing with form inputs - seems like you have `radio`/`checkbox` inputs due to their `checked` property. Also, `this.checked` returns a boolean so there's no need for `$(this).is(':checked')` either.

---

I believe your logic can be simplified to:

```
function getSingleCheckedItemId() {
    return $(".data-table-chk-item:checked").val();
}
```

This way [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will return the value of the first `:checked` item or `undefined` if no elements are matched by the selector, which does the same as the loop above.

Comment: you don't have to: `var ret = $(this).attr("value");` under that function... just `ret = $(this).attr("value");` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it:

```
function getSingelCheckedItemId() {
    var elements = $(".data-table-chk-item:checked");
    return (elements.length > 0) ? $(elements[0]).val() : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
function getSingleCheckedItemId() {
    var ret;
    $(".data-table-chk-item").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            ret = $(this).attr("value");
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the return false break out of the getSingleCheckedItem and return false instead of the ret value?

Comment: Nope, the `return false` does not affect the return value of `.each`, and this answer does not use the return value of `.each` either. `=]` It breaks out of .each earlier only. http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/4xqFG/1/